# Where is my service getting it's constructor arguments from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm learning about services and my tutorial creates a service:

```
services.AddTransient<IMailService, NullMailService>();
```

Where NullMailService is defined as below:

```
public class NullMailService : IMailService
  {
    private readonly ILogger<NullMailService> _logger;

    public NullMailService(ILogger<NullMailService> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
      // Log the message
      _logger.LogInformation($"To: {to} Subject: {subject} Body: {body}");
    }
  }
```

This is then implemented in an action

```
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;

    public AppController(IMailService mailService)
    {
      _mailService = mailService;
    }
```

And the _mailService object can then be used to access the SendMessage method.

What I'm not understanding is where the 'logger' variable in the NullMailService constructor is initialised? It is never passed an ILogger < NullMailService > as an argument so I don't understand where, when and how it receives/defines this logger variable.

Comment: not just `ILogger`, there are many other built-in services for you to use via DI. Of course many of them are essential and registered by default (with some default implementation) when configuring the host and the app (default even by the way of creating a new project and not even need your care about it). Some are required to be explicitly registered (e.g: `IHttpContextAccessor`, ...). So just try injecting the services and once it's not available, you can research for how to register them. Trying to know all about the built-in services is good so that u don't feel embarrassed when using them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your program class you have this code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Host is an object that encapsulates an app's resources, such as Logging or Dependency injection (DI) and many more.

So Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) adds by default the logging providers (among many other services) to use.

You can see in the code a Startup class. Startup class includes a ConfigureServices method to configure the app's services. A service is a reusable component that provides app functionality. Services are registered in ConfigureServices and consumed across the app via dependency injection (DI) or ApplicationServices.

Initially, the IServiceCollection of ConfigureServices has services defined by the framework depending on how the host was configured.

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger and
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory are just small samples of these framework-registered services.

Comment: To expand on this.  In the startup.cs file under the ConfigureServices method you can add other objects that you can inject into your MailService the same way ILogger<T> is injected.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming then that, similarly to the AddTransient method, which 'replaces' implementations of a named interface with a named type, the same is true for ILogger <T> (i.e.ILogger<T> is replaced with a defined type?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection to find out more and to learn what AddSingleton, AddTransient and AddScoped do. In basic terms, they define the lifecycle of the object being injected.

Comment: I think my confusion was more around not being able to find where it explicitly adds/defines the ILogger service. They're a framework provided service, which makes sense - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#framework-provided-services. I'll give that a read though!

Comment: it's not really a 'replacement of the implementations', but rather an instruction. Think of `services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>()` as: "If you ever see an IMailservice in a constructor of a class as a dependency, construct MailService." This can go on recursively (if MailService got it's dependencies too and those have their ones). It will construct them all, given you provide those instructions in your Startup.cs .